# how to get associative indexes of an array which has a specific value

Tags: php, associative-array

```
    {
    [2012-05-23] => 1
    [2012-05-24] => 1
    [2012-05-25] => 1
    [2012-05-26] => 1
    [2012-05-27] => 1
    [2012-05-28] => 11
    [2012-05-29] => 11
    [2012-05-30] => 12
    }
```

for example this is my array and i just want to get the indexes of array which has a value greater then 10

so in this case the answer must be sounded like that

```
    {
    [0] => 2012-05-28
    [1] => 2012-05-29
    [2] => 2012-05-30
     }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$array` is your first array :

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if( $value > 10 ) {
        $new_array[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

someone like this!

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $r => $a)
{
    if ($a>10)
    $new_array[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: This would give you an array of the values, not the dates.

Comment: Sorry for the Ctrl+V Ctrl+C mistake!
Now, it's fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=//Your array in original post.
$newarray=array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    if ($key>10) {
        $newarray[]=$key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that the array in `<pre>` is called `$dates`):

```
$result = array();
foreach($dates as $date => $value) {
    if($value > 10) $result[] = $date;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$testData = array ('2012-05-23' => 1,
                   '2012-05-24' => 1, 
                   '2012-05-25' => 1,
                   '2012-05-26' => 1, 
                   '2012-05-27' => 1, 
                   '2012-05-28' => 11, 
                   '2012-05-29' => 11, 
                   '2012-05-30' => 12,
                   );
$testNeedle = 10;

$result = array_filter($testData, 
                       function($arrayEntry) use ($testNeedle) {
                           return $arrayEntry > $testNeedle; 
                       }
);
$result = array_keys($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job.

```
$array1 = array(
'2012-05-23' => 1,
'2012-05-24' => 1,
'2012-05-25' => 1,
'2012-05-26' => 1,
'2012-05-27' => 1,
'2012-05-28' => 11,
'2012-05-29' => 11,
'2012-05-30' => 12
);
$result = (array_keys(array_filter($array1, "select")));
function select($var)
{    return($var > 10);     }
```

You can also use a for loop with array_push in an empty array to skip the callback function.